# why this php code just output a part?

Tags: php, list, while-loop, each

```
<?php
    $products = array(
        array("name"=>"apple", "count"=>1),
        array("name"=>"google", "count"=>2),
        array("name"=>"ms", "count"=>4)
    );
    echo "one:<br/>";
    for ($i=0; $i < count($products); $i++) {
        foreach ($products[$i] as $key => $value) {
            echo $key."-".$value.",";
        } 
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    echo "<br/>two:<br/>";
    for ($j=0; $j < count($products); $j++) {
        while(list($k, $v) = each($products[$j])){
            echo $k."|".$v.",";
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

this code just output:

```
one:
name-apple,count-1,
name-google,count-2,
name-ms,count-4,

two:
```

i want to know why the two part not output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the internal array pointer for each sub-array is already at the end of the array, and when you try to use `each()` there is nothing to return. Try this:

```
echo "<br/>two:<br/>";
for ($j=0; $j < count($products); $j++) {
    reset( $products[$j]);
    while(list($k, $v) = each($products[$j])){
        echo $k."|".$v.",";
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

All it's doing is calling [`reset()`](http://php.net/reset) to reset the array pointer.